# Is it posible for Shopify web app to communicate with custom web app?

Tags: angular, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have a Shopify website where all my products are available, and where the user is logged in. I also have a custom web app (in angular) that can, from a series of questions make an order with the Shopify API. On the Shopify web app, there is a button that takes the user to the custom web app. The problem is I want the customer_id, email, or some other form of identification from Shopify to the custom web app after the user pressed the button. One idea I had was for the button to use the url: https://generate-app/customer_id=[customer_id]

The problem with this is I'm not sure how to make a button with a redirect URL that has the customer_id.

Comment: You can look into [Shopify app proxies](https://shopify.dev/apps/online-store/app-proxies). Each request made through the app proxy includes the customer's id. Then use the proxy link as the redirect url for your button.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain perhaps a little better what is going on here? What is the Shopify web app? What does it have to do with Shopify? You know you could just build your customizer out as a theme app extension, and therefore have a lot more integrated control with the customer and the shopping experience? Anyway, without a lot more details from you, I do not think your question is even remotely answerable.